# how to build a textfield with caption and text area in the same line Vaadin

Tags: java, web, frameworks, vaadin

i was implementing a text field to get some user data (new to vaadin)

when i initialize the textfield using

```
 new TextField("caption");
```

i am using reindeer theme 
how can i get the text field as this :

```
caption: textarea //same line
```

instead of

```
caption: //different lines
textarea
```

should i override the default css and how to do it?????
or is there any method availble for this??????

Comment: you might want to look at [this thread](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/41180) on Vaadin forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `FormLayout`.

```
FormLayout fl = new FormLayout();
TextField tf = new TextField("caption"); 
fl.addComponent(tf);
```

More information in the Vaadin Book [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.formlayout.html).